# Load testing strategies for network server applications

Tags: .net, performance, networking, network-programming, load-testing

I am building a Windows service that listens for connections over TCP and, once a connection is established, sends a steady stream of data.  It is very simple... once the initial request is made, the communication is one-way (on the application layer, of course).

What is a good way to test this with significant load, say up to 3,000 simultaneous connections?  Are there standard tools for this kind of thing, or should I just write my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the feeling you have written your own protocol, so I think you're like stuck to implementing your own load testing client.

Writing a load testing client for something like this isn't hard. The only thing I would advise though is to really think about whether you're going to test on a connection from one physical machine or multiple. I'm not saying you should test from 3,000 physical machines, but something like 10 or 20 machines would be a good idea. Otherwise you have a good chance the client machine being the bottleneck.

Also, to really test the server, you have to have a good load test implementation. If you see the processor usage of your load tester staying at 100%, you're not testing the server; you're testing the client.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I think I will likely go this route.  Perhaps when I am done, I will build a generic test utility and release it for others to use.  Something that can send a pre-defined chunk of data to a server, and accept a response.  I am not-so-confident in my optimization abilities, which is why I was hoping a standard tool already exists, but checking for the condition of the tester being overloaded is easy enough.  Thanks again.

Comment: Well, the best advise I can give is to go for an async implementation (`BeginRead`/`BeginWrite`) instead of multiple processes. This is one of the most important points and will increase your throughput of the client.